# Stop script if nc connetion succeded in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, netcat

How can I stop my script if the connection with netcat was successful?
For example if `Connection to 192.168.2.4 21 port [tcp/ftp] succeeded!` I'm not sure what holds that string of text.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Find first 3 octets of the gateway and set it to a variable.

GW=$(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c1-10)

#loop through 1 to 255 on the 4th octect 
for octet4 in {1..255}
do
        sleep .2
        nc -w1 $GW$octet4 21

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for `nc` exit status.

Eg.:

```
nc -w1 $GW$octet4 21
[[ "$?" -eq 0 ]] && exit
```

If command `nc` succeeded and return zero exit status which is implicitly stored in `$?` shell variable, `exit` the script. Or use just `break` instead of `exit` if you want to just jump out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the return code from `nc`, then break when it is equal to 0. Here is an example script that iterates until it hits googles DNS server IP `8.8.8.8` then breaks.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}; do
    sleep 1;
    echo Trying 8.8.8.$i
    nc -w1 8.8.8.$i 53
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Your script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Find first 3 octets of the gateway and set it to a variable.

GW=$(route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c1-10)

#loop through 1 to 255 on the 4th octect 
for octet4 in {1..255}
do
        sleep .2
        nc -w1 $GW$octet4 21
        if [ $? == 0 ]
        then
            break
        fi
done
```